# Error "Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.route')" when trying to pass properties to a second screen in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

So Im trying to pass some properties to one screen to another in react-native (with expo) and appears this error: *Error "Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.route')"* every time.Im using route params to pass the text specified in props tag "Jane". I've used other variations but always appear this same error.

My code is

Screen 1:

```
export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState([]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Search Your Next Amazing Poem By Author, Or Keyword</Text>
      ...
       <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('PoemsAuthor'), {props: 'Jane'}}}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Search</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  );
}
```

SCREEN 2:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';


export default function PoemsAuthorScreen({ navigation, route }){
    const {props} = this.route.params;
    const {poetry, setPoetry} = setState("")
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: "https://thundercomb-poetry-db-v1.p.rapidapi.com/author/william shakespeare",
            headers: {
              'x-rapidapi-key': 'a0f62248edmsha80f5f690d48e62p1ac60djsnc0f5ecf310ba',
              'x-rapidapi-host': 'thundercomb-poetry-db-v1.p.rapidapi.com'
            }
          }; 
          
          axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
              setPoetry(response.data);
          }).catch(function (error) {
              console.error(error);
          });       
    })
              
        return (
            <View>
          {/*<Text> { poetry.map(element => 
                <Text> {element.author} {element.title} </Text>)}
          </Text>*/}
          <Text>{JSON.stringify(props)}</Text>
            </View>
             
            
        )}
```

I appreciate any help as I dont have any idea what is happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your `PoemsAuthorScreen` is a function component and not a class.

To access to the props, you don't need `this.`

```js
const {props} = route.params;
```